# Benefits of Token Exchange protocol in OAuth 2

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, rfc

Beginner question here, I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around the security benefits of **the token exchange protocol** as specified by [RFC8693](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693).  To me it seems like a delegation pattern where a webservice (**service A**) impersonates the authenticated user when accessing another webservice (**service B**).  It does so by swapping the authenticated user token (**public token**) for a different token (**internal token**) issued to Service A while retaining the identity of the authenticated user.

Seems to me that the only benefits here are

1. The internal token may contain claims and scopes required for Service B to perform its functionaly, which are not included in the public token.
2. Service B can be isolated and therefore safe from random attacks
3. Service B does not need to authenticate the user since it only deals with requests coming from Service A

But it doesn't really protect from playback attacks since if you gain access to the public token, then you have access to the internal token by proxy, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The Token Exchange just defines the endpoint and parameters. This leaves many things up to the implementer and architect of the system.

Some interesting quotes from the spec:

> The entity that makes the request to exchange tokens is considered the client in the context of the token exchange interaction. However, that does not restrict usage of this profile to traditional OAuth clients. An OAuth resource server, for example, might assume the role of the client during token exchange in order to trade an access token that it received in a protected resource request for a new token that is appropriate to include in a call to a backend service. The new token might be an access token that is more narrowly scoped for the downstream service or it could be an entirely different kind of token.
>
> [...]
>
> The security tokens obtained may be used in a number of contexts, the specifics of which are also beyond the scope of this specification.

([RFC 8693, Introduction](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693#name-introduction))

1. The client might be an backend (as you mention in your question) or a normal OAuth client.
2. The token might be a different kind of token. This would allow the integration of [other token types](https://fly.io/blog/api-tokens-a-tedious-survey/) for some specific services without needing to migrate all systems to one token type. So both OAuth client and backend API (also a client in the spec’s context) may exchange tokens for something different.
3. Another use case might be changing the allowed audience and resource of the exchanged token, based on some policy. This also enables usage of the token at other resources.

> Whereas, `urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt` is to indicate specifically that a JWT is being requested or sent (perhaps in a cross-domain use case where the JWT is used as an authorization grant to obtain an access token from a different authorization server as is facilitated by [RFC7523]).

([RFC 8693, Section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693#section-3-5))

Above snippet mentions another use case: A protected resource R might only accept access token from issuer A whereas a backend / client has only access token issued by B. The authorization server of issuer A might solve this by implementing RFC 8693 issuing access token if access token from issuer B are presented by an authorized client. This token exchange presupposes that A trusts B.

Regarding your proxying question:

> The supported methods of client authentication and whether or not to allow unauthenticated or unidentified clients are deployment decisions that are at the discretion of the authorization server. Note that omitting client authentication allows for a compromised token to be leveraged via an STS into other tokens by anyone possessing the compromised token. Thus, client authentication allows for additional authorization checks by the STS as to which entities are permitted to impersonate or receive delegations from other entities.

([RFC 8693, Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693#section-2.1-2))

The spec’s authors were aware of the security implications. In your example of a backend service exchanging the token, the backend’s client might be required to authenticate at the token endpoint.